# Fetch all data from database row?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

How do i fetch all data from database row?

At the moment this is my Query:

```
try{
    $results = $db->query("SELECT name, id FROM players ORDER BY name ASC");
    $results->execute();
    // echo "Our query ran successfully.";
} catch (Exception $e){
    echo "Data could not be retrived from the database.";
    exit;
}

while ($row = $results->fetch()) {
    $joukkue    =   ($row["name"]);
    $id         =   ($row["id"]);
}
```

and this shows one database item: `echo $name;`

but how can i get the whole row?

My end goal is to echo the data into a form select tag example:

```
<select id="select1" name="select">
    <option selected="selected" >Stuff here</option>
</select>
```

PS: I am using PDO to connect to my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM players ORDER BY name ASC

<select id="select1" name="select">
  <?php
    while ($row = $results->fetch()) {
      echo '<option>'. $row["name"] .'</option>';
    }
  ?>
</select>
```

Comment: but how do i echo them all out?

Comment: Do you know the columns beforehand or not? If you don't know the columns, then you can try:
    print_r($row);

Comment: I know the columns. But i need to echo them inside the select form tag.

Comment: See updated answer, you need to print each option out within the select tag using the while loop.